# Найти повторяющиеся элементы в списке, используя while, if , for in

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, как будет выглядеть код, который находит повторяющиеся элементы в списке с использованием циклов.

Допустим, список: `[1,2,3,1,1,1,2,3,3,2,2,]`
вывод:

```
1:4
2:4
3:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,2,1,3,2,1]
counter ={}
for el in list1:
    if el not in counter:
        c=0
        for n in list1:
            if n==el:
                c+=1
        counter[el]=c
print(counter)
```

Comment: спасибо больше , пошел разбирать ))

Comment: могли бы пожалуйста обьяснить строки - 
for n in list1:
            if n==el:
                c+=1
        counter[el]=c

Comment: Выбираем элемент, если он равен нашему опорному (el) то переменную кол-ва увеличиваем на один

Comment: counter[el]=c - а это получается мы присваиваем к элементу то кол-во раз сколько оно повторяется ?

Comment: @Maks да. Именно так.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = {}
for i in [1,2,3,1,1,1,2,3,3,2,2,]:
    try: r[i] += 1
    except: r[i] = 1
print(r)
```