# Python как узнать повторяющиеся элементы в списке

Tags: python

Как найти повторяющиеся элементы в списке?

Вот input:

```
4 3
111
110
001
110
```

output:

```
2 (т.к. 110 встретился дважды)
```

мой код:

```
N, M = map(int, input().split())
a = [[int(i) for i in input().split()] for j in range(N)]
for i in range(a):
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Найти повторяющиеся элементы в списке, используя while, if , for in](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1085963/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-while-if-for-in)

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

mylist = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
counter = [k for k, v in Counter(mylist).items() if v > 1]

print(len(counter))
```

Comment: выходит ошибка 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 5, in <module>
    counter = [k for k, v in Counter(mylist).items() if v > 1]
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 552, in __init__
    self.update(iterable, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 637, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: можно ваш код? особенно то как формируете список

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать через словарь:

```py
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]
d = {}
# Составим словарь по кол-во повторений
for i in mylist:
    if i in d:
        d[i] += 1
    else:
        d[i] = 1

# Получим только повторяющиеся данные
for k, v in d.items():
    if v > 1:
        print(f"{k} встречается {v} раз")
```

Вариант если на входе список списков:

```py
l = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [5, 6]]
mylist = sum(l, []) # По сути единственное отличие от пред варианта 
d = {}
for i in mylist:
    if i in d:
        d[i] += 1
    else:
        d[i] = 1

for k, v in d.items():
    if v > 1:
        print(f"{k} встречается {v} раз")
```

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @alkeysmagul Странная ошибка если честно...  Могу сказать что у меня в скрипте работает как мой так и код Sky. Посоветовал бы переустановить python но это несколько радикальный вариант.

Comment: @Kers, обратите на эту строку в вопросе: `a = [[int(i) for i in input().split()] for j in range(N)]` - там по сути список списков на входе (список списков из одного элемента, если быть точным).

Comment: @insolor возможно, хотя в исходном  условии это не очевидно. Решается имхо несложно `newlist = sum(mylist, [])` на всякий случай дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В случае, если нужно найти определенный элемент:

```
c=int(input()) # вводим элемент, количество которого хотим найти

a,b=list(map(int, input().split()))
d=[]
for i in range(a):
    s=int(input())
    d.append(s)

print(d.count(c))
```

В случае, если нужно найти максимальное количество повторяющихся элементов:

```
a,b=list(map(int, input().split()))
d=[]
m=[]
for i in range(a):
    s=int(input())
    d.append(s)

for i in range(len(d)):
    m.append(d.count(d[i]))
print(max(m))
```